# ant tag to ignore <copy todir> if destination directory doesn't exist

Tags: java, ant, pom.xml

Do we have any Ant tags under `copy todir` to ignore copying a file if destination directory is empty?
I need this to implement coz I need to ignore copying the jar file if the destination directory doesn't exist. If I don't do this, then build fails as it'll not be able to find the destination folder.

I went through the below link but I didn't get any information on such tag.
[Apache Ant Tags for Copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)

Comment: I think `failonerror` should be good. Need comfirmation.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Setting the `failonerror` attribute to `false` will log an error message, but will not abort the build. If, additionally, you want to get rid of the error message, you can set the `quiet` attribute to `true`.

Comment: Yeah, it worked perfectly fine. The link I posted has the tag right there, but I was in hurry so didn't concentrate on all tags. So,`failonerror` with `quite` is proper combination.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to

you can to mkdir in ant to create dir if it doesnt exist

if it exists it does nothing